# Create object snapshot

Tags: dart, dart-pub, object-serialization

I'm tinkering with [transformers](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/assets-and-transformers.html)  + ["analyzer" pub packages](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer) and I want to build a 2 stage transformer.

The stages are:

1. Build [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) for each dart source file.
2. Generate new sources from the first stage outputs(with information from all ASTs).

I need to pass AST from one stage to another without costly serialization/deserialization, but `Asset`([docs](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/barback/barback.Asset)) can't be build from a class instances.

**Is it possible to build a class instance snapshot and pass it into the next stage?**

*That's what I have  found so far:*

[From "Snapshots in Dart" article](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/snapshots/):

> The Dart VM uses the following kinds of snapshots:
>   ...
>   An **object snapshot**. Messaging from one isolate to another is implemented in the Dart VM by creating a snapshot of the Dart object that needs to be sent to the other isolate.

[API docs for dart:isolate](https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-isolate.SendPort#id_send,message):

> In the special circumstances when two isolates share the same code and
>   are running in the same process (e.g. isolates created via spawn), it
>   is also possible to send object instances (which would be copied in
>   the process).

**If "object snapshot" has the same restrictions, then it can't help me.**

But, Interestingly enough, it should be possible to create a "deep copy"(clone) of an object by looping it through spawned isolate.

In  [Issue 6459:    clone instance(object)](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=6459) @lrn pointed out:

> We generally don't want ways to create an object that are not going
>   through the class' generative constructors.  You can read what Joshua
>   Bloch says about clone in Java:
>   http://www.artima.com/intv/bloch13.html Even with that experience in
>   mind, we might be able to avoid the interface problems, but we can't
>   generally decide whether a deep or a shallow copy is the right thing
>   to do. Only the object itself knows that.

So it's not recommended even if possible.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [code_transformers package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/code_transformers)?

Comment: That's what I use for [zengen](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/zengen). See https://github.com/a14n/zengen/blob/8ee849d44131b55fef6f5205c2a036d99685c73b/lib/transformer.dart#L68-L74

Comment: @AlexandreArdhuin That's really cool. I was thinking about writing something like memoizer(@Cached in yours package), tail recursion optimization and stuff for debugging like call logger, asserter..